# How to stop Auto HTML anchors added to heading tags in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Is it possible to prevent anchors being automatically added to the heading tags in WordPress 5.7.1?

It looks like some sort of JS is adding the HTML anchor when you edit a post.

This is duplicating anchors in my headings added by my table of contents plugin. All my headings appears as follows:

```
<h2 id="heading"><span id="Heading">Heading</span></h2>
```

I would like to eliminated the anchor that appears in the heading tag.

I am aware that my WordPress version is old. Just checking if there is a way I can resolve this without updating WordPress.

Comment: It looks like the option to disable automatic anchors was added after 5.9.1 (starting by version 6? not sure about it). But if updating Wordpress is a no go for you, you could try to apply those specific commits to your code. Either via a plugin or a patch
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/38780